# open link from chrome to firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, shortcut-keys

I've got two browsers open, chrome and firefox, and would like to have a shortcut to be able to open a link I have in chrome as a new tab in my firefox window. Right now I do this by clicking 'Copy link address' in Chrome and pasting the URL into firefox, but I would like to have a shortcut defined to do this. Is this doable?

Comment: Chrome used to have an extension called "Open with external application" that did exactly what you want. I still have it installed on my version of Chrome (37.something), but it's no longer available from Chrome/Google. Exporting this hasn't worked, and simply copying the extension folder to a new location hasn't worked either. Maybe someone has seen this old extension archived somewhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you considered just dragging the link? I use both browsers at the same time (each on it's own screen). I find myself mostly using Chrome for gmail etc.. and will get links via email. I just click and drag from Chrome to the Firefox tab bar and the page will open in a new tab. It works in the other direction too (Firefox to Chrome). One needn't limit this to email... basically any link on any page will work via this method.

Comment: I can confirm this works. However, a possible limitation: what if the OP has both browsers open fullscreen?

Comment: What a cool tip, never occurred to me to try that.

Answer (score 2):

(time warp :)

I just tried "External Application Launcher" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/external-application-laun/bifmfjgpgndemajpeeoiopbeilbaifdo

and it worked fine.

Google Chrome Version 109.0.5414.119
openSUSE Leap 15.4

HTH

Comment: Wow, pretty cool! Requires an additional [local client](https://github.com/andy-portmen/native-client) to be installed (but the extension prompts you for it, very UX-friendly) and then you can configure the functionality you need, such as "Open in Firefox". Shows up as an item in the right-click context menu. Good stuff, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Might this link be of any handy?
http://npopson.com/archives/1022
I believe it's pretty much up for google'ing or somehow changing the chrome's protocols (although there's no in-browser alternative for about:config as in firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Opera has a feature to open the current page in another browser. I don't know what your use case is, but if you need to compare web pages for website development, you could open it in Opera first then right click and open in Chrome, then do the same for Firefox.